# Nested Loops Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-loops

Hi I am working with nested loops but can not figure out a way to start a new row for my nested loop below:

```
for i in range(0,10):   
    for j in range(10):
        print(i,end =" ")
```

Output

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9

The output I want is:

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2

and so on

Answer (score 5):

Thank you but I found the answer!

```
for i in range(0,10):
    for j in range(10):
        print(i, end=" ")
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

This (and minor variations) also work:

```
for i in range(10):
    print((('%s '%i)*10)[:-1])
```